# Adding variables in a string with multiple quotation marks

Tags: python, pandas

I want these 2 string variables in my other string :

```
{"prompt":"**String 1**","completion":" **String 2**"}
```

The problem is I run into a problem because of the multiple quotations.

```
file_object = open('Sample.txt', 'a')
x = "hello"
y = "hi"
file_object.write('{"prompt":"{}","completion":" {}"}'.format(x,y))
```

This is what I have tried but It doesn't work.

My intended output : `{"prompt":"hello","completion":" hi"}`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to write JSON data. Have a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package (especially `json.dump`) for that.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb - regardless of whether you'd be better using `json` or not, it's probably that you didn't close the file and flush the contents to disk. I can't see an error in your quotation marks

Comment: Also, you should just use the `json` package from the stdlib as others have suggested.

Comment: @Axe319 yeah the answer to that problem actually worked, the problem was that I had to use double curly-braces in the begining and in the end : file_object.write('{{"prompt":"{}","completion":" {}"}}'.format(x,y))

Comment: `json.dumps({ 'prompt': { } })` is *way* easier than fighting against quoting.